How can I create a search box for WinForms?
I need some help creating a search box in WinForms (similar to the search box in Windows 11 Task Manager; see image below).
It should support an icon at the start, and a "clear" button at the end.
I have attempted to create one myself using compositing, but the problem I have is that the search button sits on top of the textbox, which allows text to be typed underneath it.  ugly.
If I composite using a panel with a "Window" background color, the whole layout issue is dealt with, but when the textbox receives focus, the blue focus bar is not rendered across the entire control, making it look out of place on a Form with multiple textboxes.
Can anybody help me solve either one of those problems?



Something like this isn't really feasible in WinForms without a load of custom-painting. I recommend you switch to WPF/WinUI.

@Dai is correct, you can do it in WinForms, but you will have to do a lot of low-level editing that 3rd parties have already done for you. Xaml based frameworks have a more declarative process for this so they will be more appropriate if you want to manage the look and feel beyond what you get OOTB in WinForms and do not want to purchase a 3rd party library that has already done this.

The icon can be rendered in OnPaint, and the button can be simply added by the Controls.Add method. To make them enough space just use the EM_SETMARGINS window message. And for the cue text just use the PlaceholderText property (available since .NET Core 3.0)

@shingo That's Windows11 standard theme?

shingo & Ralf - it's the default Win 11 theme.  That's the search box from Task Manager on Windows 11.

@GyörgyKőszeg - I tried EM_SETMARGINS and either I did something not right, or it doesn't work.  I read somewhere that EM_SETMARGINS only works on multiline textboxes.. but I can't find confirmation of that.

An example of a custom TextBox Control that should show a behavior similar (give or take) to the Control described in the question.

This Control traps WM_NCCALCSIZE to redefine the non-Client Area.
The combined regions describe a non-client left side dedicated to show an image and a bottom-side region that allows to paint the outline
WM_NCCALCSIZE is also triggered when one of the public properties that this Control exposes - used to redefine the outline's Color and size - are set at run-time or design-time
The Image object and the outline are then painted in the non-Client regions when the WM_NCPAINT message is received.
The watermark (Cue Banner) is activated sending the EM_SETCUEBANNER message to the underlying Win32 Control. WParam is set to non-zero, allowing to show the Cue Banner when the Control has focus. The Cue Banner is removed when some text is typed in, or the Control is clicked twice
There's a call to SetWindowTheme(), just because I like it better this way. Modify as required (i.e., you can remove that call, it's not strictly required; see whether you prefer it like this. Some changes to the rendering procedure may become necessary)

This is how it works at run-time. The same should apply at design-time, I haven't added anything that prevents it:


using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ToolboxItem(true), DesignerCategory("code")]
public class TextBoxOutline : TextBox {
    int outlineHeight = 1;
    Color outlineColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    Image? lensImage = null;
    int imagePadding = 0;

    public TextBoxOutline() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        lensImage = [Some Image];
        imagePadding = Height + 4;
    }

    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int OutlineHeight { 
        get => outlineHeight;
        set {
            if (value != outlineHeight) {
                outlineHeight = Math.Max(Math.Min(value, 4), 1);
                InvokeNcCalcSize();
            }
        } 
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Highlight")]
    public Color OutlineColor { 
        get => outlineColor;
        set {
            if (value != outlineColor) { 
                outlineColor = value;
                Invalidate();
                InvokeNcCalcSize();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        SetWindowTheme(Handle, "", "");
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 1, "Placeholder Text");
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
                WmNcCalcSize(ref m);
                break;
            case WM_NCPAINT:
                WmNcPaint(ref m);
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void WmNcCalcSize(ref Message m) {
        if (nint.Zero == m.WParam) {
            var client = Marshal.PtrToStructure<RECT>(m.LParam);
            client.Left += imagePadding;
            client.Bottom -= outlineHeight;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(client, m.LParam, true);
            m.Result = nint.Zero;
        }
        else {
            var calcParams = Marshal.PtrToStructure<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS>(m.LParam);
            calcParams.rgrc[0].Left += imagePadding;
            calcParams.rgrc[0].Bottom -= outlineHeight;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(calcParams, m.LParam, true);
            m.Result = 0x0010 | 0x0020 | 0x0300;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void WmNcPaint(ref Message m) {
        nint hDC = nint.Zero;
        bool deleteDC = false;
        Rectangle clipRegion = Rectangle.Empty;

        if (1 == m.WParam) {
            deleteDC = true;
            hDC = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
            clipRegion = new Rectangle(imagePadding, 0, Width - imagePadding, Height - outlineHeight);
        }
        else {
            hDC = GetDCEx(Handle, m.WParam, DCX_WINDOW | DCX_USESTYLE);
        }

        if (hDC != nint.Zero) {
            using var g = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);
            using var pen = new Pen(outlineColor, outlineHeight);
            g.Clear(BackColor);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.DrawImage(lensImage!, 0, 0, ClientSize.Height - 4, ClientSize.Height - 4);

            if (clipRegion != Rectangle.Empty) {
                g.ExcludeClip(clipRegion);
            }

            g.DrawLine(pen, 0,
                g.VisibleClipBounds.Bottom - 1,
                g.VisibleClipBounds.Width,
                g.VisibleClipBounds.Bottom - 1
            );

            if (deleteDC) ReleaseDC(Handle, hDC);
        }
        m.Result = nint.Zero;
    }

    private void InvokeNcCalcSize() {
        SetWindowPos(Handle, nint.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSENDCHANGING);
    }

    const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;
    const int WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083;
    const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085;
    const uint DCX_WINDOW = 0x00000001;
    const uint DCX_EXCLUDERGN = 0x00000040;
    const uint DCX_INTERSECTRGN = 0x00000080;
    const uint DCX_USESTYLE = 0x00010000;
    const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const uint SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    const uint SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    const uint SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int SendMessage(nint hWnd, int msg, int wParam, string lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetWindowPos(nint hWnd, nint hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("UxTheme.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern nint SetWindowTheme(nint hwnd, string pszSubAppName, string pszSubIdList);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern nint GetDCEx(nint hWnd, nint hrgnClip, uint flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern nint GetWindowDC(nint hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool ReleaseDC(nint hWnd, nint hDc);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public RECT[] rgrc;
        public WINDOWPOS lppos;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct WINDOWPOS {
        public nint hwnd;
        public nint hwndInsertAfter;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public uint flags;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RECT {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
            Left = left; Top = top; Right = right; Bottom = bottom;
        }
        public static RECT FromRectangle(Rectangle r) => new(r.Left, r.Top, r.Bottom, r.Right);

        public Rectangle ToRectangle() => Rectangle.FromLTRB(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
        public Size Size => new(Right - Left, Bottom - Top);
    }
}


Wow @Jimi!  That's a lot of work, and I sure appreciate it.  Unfortunately, it doesn't address the concern.  I know I didn't come right out and say it in the question, but it's alluded to:  I need a control that uses the OS theme for textboxes.  The blue focus bar doesn't exist on Win10 - and who knows what Win12 will bring.  I am trying to create a control that will have the same visuals as the OS, and so be themed the same as the other textboxes on the form.  Thanks again, I appreciate the effort.

I thought you were asking about a Control that replicates that kind of style. It's kind of simpler in the case you want to preserve the System Theme: you can see that, in this Control, I'm creating two sections in the non-Client Area, one to paint the outline and one to paint the Bitmap (but you could use ControlPaint to paint a Button in its different states). So, you just need to keep the region on the left; or, with the same means, generate another region, on the right side, where you can host a Button, or whatever else. The presence of the outline is then based on the System Theme alone

I'm running into a few gotchas with the NC painting.. but it has promise.  Thank you for pointing me in this direction.

Don't feel obligated to accept the answer if this is not what you're looking for. BTW, when I have a moment, I'm going to post a modified implementation -- NC painting can be initially unfriendly, mostly because in WinForms you're used to receive a PaintEventArgs object that already considers the clipping region, you can ignore that part. Then there's the WParam thing: when it's non-zero, GetDcEx() always returns a null region; when it's zero, the System wants you to validate the region, you must call it with an undocumented flag, DCX_USESTYLE, and DCX_EXCLUDERGN when needed, etc.

Thanks Jimi.  I don't feel obligated.  I do feel appreciative that your answer has put me on a more productive path than I was on.  I feel that ultimately it will lead me to the correct solution - thus the accepted answer.    If you happen to post your updated solution sometime I would be interested in perusing it.  The NC painting in WinForms is, as you say, a bit unfriendly.

Call 911!.

@dr.null Well, by posting here, we give up intellectual ownership. Not sure whether this should be flagged, to let the company know and take action, if they decide so. I'll see if there's a similar discussion in Meta (unless you already know)

Yes, I found that while I was googling around. It would be right to give credit to the author and link this page. Otherwise, it's plagiarism. We don't ask for anything else in return.

You can customise the way the text box is drawn by overriding the OnPaint method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/overriding-the-onpaint-method?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
